# I need to create Android keyboard app, but some classes are depricated

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, uikeyboard, android-input-method, input-method-kit

I need to develope android keyboard app, but Android developers website tells that `KeyboardView` and `Keybord` classes are deprecated after Api 29, to create the UI for the keyboard.

This class was deprecated in API level 29. The following is the message I found:

***This class is deprecated because this is just a convenient UI widget class that application developers can re-implement on top of existing public APIs. If you have already depended on this class, consider copying the implementation from AOSP into your project or re-implementing a similar widget by yourselves***

So how shall I develope the app if the classes won't work after Api 29? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution Google suggests is copying [KeyboardView.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/b798689749c64baba81f02e10cf2157c747d6b46/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java) and [Keyboard.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.java) files to your local project from Android AOSP. With some customization I managed to make it work as old **deprecated** `KeyboardView` and `Keyboard` Android's classes.

You will also have your local copy of **com.android.internal.R** attributes (stylable) from  [from here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml#7740)

You can notice, it is annotated as

```
<!-- {@deprecated Copy this definition into your own application project.} -->
```